# problema con sweetalert y promesa

Tags: javascript

```
swal({
title: "prueba",
text: "pregunta prueba",
icon: "warning",
buttons: true,
dangerMode: true,
})
.then((respuesta) => {
if (respuesta) {
    swal("prueba");
    swal("prueba 2");
} else {
    swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
}
});
```

Al ejecutar esta promesa con SweetAlert, la funcion swal con el texto prueba 2 no se llega ejecutar nunca, no entiendo el por que, lo he probado de todas las maneras pero este es mi ultimo recurso.

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido` sweetalert `no puede mostrar dos notificaciones al mismo tiempo.

Comment: pero hay alguna otra forma de mostrarlas? o debo usar otra libreria?

Comment: Podrías probar con librerías que provean snackbars en vez de alerts